# Installing SQL Server Management Studio when VS2010 Beta 2 is already installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

This is driving me nuts --

I installed VS2010 B2 -- It installed SQLEXPRESS -- I went into the 'SQL Server Configuration Manager' and enabled the TCPIP protocol under 'SQL Server Network Configuration' for the SQLExpress instance.

All fine and dandy so far.
Next I downloaded the 'SQL express with ssms 2008 SP1' from MS in an attempt to install SSMS.

Once I start the installer, I go to 'Installation' and pick 'New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation', I click OK, to install the setup support files'

I pick to Add features to SQLExpress, but when I confirm that I want to install, I get:

'There are validation erros on this page. Click OK to close this dialog box. Review errors at the bottom Setup page, then provide valid parameters or click Help for more information.'

But all it says at the bottom is 'To continue one or more feature must be selected'

When everything is checked but grayed out --- Any clues ??

Comment: 1) Is SMSS among the grayed-out items? 2) Could it be installed already?

Comment: No it's not :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you better do nothing. just when the error page comes go back and select new installation (not the add features to option) and go on. Then on the page where error was coming you will notice that a check box Management tools basic is unchecked. Select it and then go on. All will goes well.

Comment: I had to cancel out and got all the way back to the SQL Server Installation Center before this worked for me.

Comment: I then had to go and to this to get the installation to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556122/error-package-microsoft-sql-management-studio-package-failed-to-load-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the separate installer looks identical -- 
I just went through it, picked a new install and it went fine -- sort of confusing if you ask me.